# Changing serviceType in kubernetes using helm upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, openshift, kubernetes-helm

We have a service already deployed as a headless service i.e clusterIp : None in production.
Now we need to change this to a non headless service i.e type should be ClusterIp and clusterIp should be set to some value other than None. 
I modified the charts and tried to deploy using helm upgrade command. But its not allowed and helm is complaining that service type is an immutable field.

kubectl edit svc also was not able to helpful.
kubectl patch also dint work.
Any workarounds for this problem other than deleting helm chart and redeploying it again?

Comment: Did you try to delete the service before running upgrade? Helm should identify the service as a missing resource, and recreate it with the new type.

Comment: What was the output of `kubectl edit svc` and `kubectl patch` ?

Comment: @EduardoBaitello Deleting a service in production during would cause a downtime right?

Comment: @Nick kubectl edit svc => can not modify immutable field.   kubectl patch => service was not patched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are speaking about Services, then ClusterIP is usually assigned by the master and is the IP address of the service.

If specified, it will be allocated to the service if it is unused or else creation of the service will fail.

Valid values are `None`, empty string (""), or a valid IP address. `None` can be specified for a [`headless service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services)  when proxying is not required.

**Cannot be updated.**

You can find Kubernetes Top Level API Objects [Documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/docs/api-reference/v1/definitions.html#spec-and-status) helpful.

Hope that sheds the light on the root cause of the issue you are facing (changing service type).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Nick.I get your point.So service type for a service can not be updated. Only option is to delete and create service again.Is there any other option you would suggest to achieve my requirement ?

Comment: As far as I can see from the documentation, it is not possibly to update/patch service without recreation (deletion of previous instance of this service).

Comment: Yes. Thanks for responding @Nick

Comment: Yes, sure. Fell free to use "accepted" if you find that useful.